# How to make active characters work differently in mathmode and text mode?

Tags: catcodes, active-characters, mathcode

Still learning about active characters, catcodes, mathcodes, and such.

I know how to make *hello* produce bold in text mode and $*x*$ produce a bold $x$ in math mode.  I also know how to make *{hello} produce bold in text mode and $*x$ produce a bold $x$ in math mode.

What I don't know is how to make *hello* produce bold in text mode and $*x$ produce a bold $x$ in math mode.  (Note the number of asterisks.)

(I've run out of upvotes for the day, but will reward good answers tomorrow)

This I can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begingroup\lccode`\~=`*\lowercase{\endgroup\def~#1~}{\ifmmode\bm{#1}\else{\bfseries #1}\fi}
\mathcode`*="8000
\catcode`*=13

\begin{document}
*this bold*  this not
$*x*$   % produces bold math
% I want $*x$ to produce a bold x
\end{document}
```

This I can do, also:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begingroup\lccode`\~=`*\lowercase{\endgroup\def~#1}{\ifmmode\bm{#1}\else{\bfseries #1}\fi}
\mathcode`*="8000
\catcode`*=13

\begin{document}
*{this bold}  this not
$*x$   % produces bold math
\end{document}
```

Comment: since you are making it globally active the `\mathcode` setting isn't doing anything (also you break other uses of `*` such as in tabular preambles.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle.  I'm in the process of learning about the process, not necessarily thinking about this particular example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\catcode`*=13
\def*{\relax\ifmmode\expandafter\bm\else\expandafter\bstar\fi}
\def\bstar#1*{\textbf{#1}}



\begin{document}
*this bold*  this not
$*x x$   % produces bold math
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not very different from David's answer, but it also fixes other usages of `*` (for variant commands and in tabular preambles).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\jpi@active@ast}{%
  \relax % in case we're in a tabular
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\jpi@active@ast@math
  \else
    \expandafter\jpi@active@ast@text
  \fi
}
\catcode`*=\active
\def*{\ifincsname\string*\else\expandafter\jpi@active@ast\fi}
\def\jpi@active@ast@text#1*{\textbf{#1}}
\let\jpi@active@ast@math\bm

% fix the kernel macros
\def\@ifstar#1{\@ifnextchar *{\@firstoftwo{#1}}} % fix \@ifstar
\def\@expast#1{\@xexpast #1*0x\@@}
\def\@xexpast#1*#2#3#4\@@{%
  \edef\reserved@a{#1}%
  \@tempcnta#2\relax
  \ifnum\@tempcnta>\z@
    \@whilenum\@tempcnta>\z@\do
       {\edef\reserved@a{\reserved@a#3}\advance\@tempcnta \m@ne}%
    \let\reserved@b\@xexpast
  \else
    \let\reserved@b\@xexnoop
  \fi
  \expandafter\reserved@b\reserved@a #4\@@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section*{Unnumbered}
*this bold*  this not
$*x$   % produces bold math
\begin{equation*}
a=*x
\end{equation*}
\begin{tabular}[t]{*{2}{c}}
a & bb \\
cc & d
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you want to use it? No, don't. `;-)`

Comment: I'll have to study your answer to understand what's going on, thank you!

Comment: Did you search `latex.ltx` for asterisks?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Yes, indeed

Comment: @egreg: I had done so too, and I was delighted in seeing that I couldn’t find anything that wasn’t cared for! :-)